# Extract City name from distance matrix api response

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to extract city name from the distance matrix api response. The city name always appear in the compound_code attribute where city name are Chennai and Bangalore in two individual responses provided below.

Example 1 :

```
{
"plus_code": {
"compound_code": "3653+Q3 Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India",
"global_code": "7M523653+Q3"
},
"results": [10 items],
"status": "OK"
}
```

Example 2:

```
{
"plus_code": {
"compound_code": "2HGX+6G Bengaluru, Karnataka, India",
"global_code": "7J5V2HGX+6G"
},
"results": [10 items],
"status": "OK"
}
```

I tried something below but it didn't work for me

```
var compoundCode= JSON.parse(body).plus_code.compound_code;
var city = compoundCode.subString(0, str.indexOf(","));
```

Am not sure how to filter out 3653+Q3 from "3656+Q3 Chennai" or 2HGX+6G from "2HGX+6G Bengaluru"

Answer (score 0):

You can target the first space and start from that point onwards.

```js
const body = {
  "plus_code": {
    "compound_code": "3653+Q3 Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India",
    "global_code": "7M523653+Q3"
  },
  "results": [],
  "status": "OK"
}
const field = body.plus_code.compound_code.trim();
const cities = field.substring(field.indexOf(' ') + 1).split(',');
console.log(cities)
```

Comment: I received "Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India" but actually wanted "Chennai". Can you help me please ?